# J2ME - using javax.microedition.amms.control.camera.CameraControl; is it possible to disable shutter sound?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

In my Blackberry app I've implemented the camera and would like to replace the default shutter sound with my own. I figured I could do this by silencing the default camera sound by using the method enableShutterFeedback(false) then playing my own sound, or playing my sound immediately before the camera is activated.

```
private void initializeCamera()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a player for the Blackberry's camera
            Player player = Manager.createPlayer( "capture://video" );

            // Set the player to the REALIZED state (see Player javadoc)
            player.realize();

            // Grab the video control and set it to the current display
            _videoControl = (VideoControl)player.getControl( "VideoControl" );

            if (_videoControl != null)
            {
                // Create the video field as a GUI primitive (as opposed to a
                // direct video, which can only be used on platforms with
                // LCDUI support.)
                _videoField = (Field) _videoControl.initDisplayMode (VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");
                _videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
                _videoControl.setVisible(false);
            }
            cc = (CameraControl)player.getControl("CameraControl");
            cc.enableShutterFeedback(false);
            // Set the player to the STARTED state (see Player javadoc)
            player.start();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MyApp.errorDialog("ERROR " + e.getClass() + ":  " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This results in a Null pointer exception but can't figure out what's causing it, the camera's video doesn't get displayed. If I remove the CameraControl code in bold then the camera's video is shown. Any ideas what I should try to get rid of the shutter sound? I tried VolumeControl in place of CameraControl, same results, null pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CameraControl code gives a NPE because `player.getControl` returns null, and it does so because the string param is not correct. Try this one:

```
CameraControl control = (CameraControl) p.getControl("javax.microedition.amms.control.camera.CameraControl");
```

Comment: Well this helped me confirm that it's not possible. The Error message displayed in the Dialog was "enableShutterFeedback is not supported". Guess RIM didn't implement this. I also tried the VolumeControl but got the same Null pointer problem.

Comment: Which OS are you developing for?

Comment: You are right, not implemented. Read 4th paragraph here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Advanced-Multimedia-Supplement-API-What-s-Supported/ta-p/770659

Comment: So obviously this method of doing things isn't going to work. I wonder how they did it in BerryAnnoying  and Peek-A-Boo.

Comment: Volume control should return not null, though: `(VolumeControl) p.getControl("VolumeControl");`